# .Net Core RequestHttpMessage AddCookies to Header in .Net Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I need to return `HttpResponseMessage` in one of my controller methods and add a cookie to it in a few cases.

I've referred through few articles but couldn't get it resolved. For instance:

- [How add Cookies to http request header in ASP .NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557338/how-add-cookies-to-http-request-header-in-asp-net-core-mvc)
- [HTTP Response Headers in ASP.NET Core](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/http-response-headers-asp-net-core/)
- [HTTP Response Headers in ASP.NET Core](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/07/18/secure-an-asp-net-core-web-api-using-cookies/)

I've used .NET Framework code similar to what's below, but I need it in .NET Core:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieToken))
{
    response.Headers.AddCookies(new[]
    {
        new CookieHeaderValue("MyCookie", cookieToken)
        {
            Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(4),
            Path = "/",
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = true,
        }
    });
}
```

So far, I've tried the below code for returning status codes and messages.

```
protected IActionResult CreateInternalServerResponse<T>(T data) =>
    StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, data);

     
var responseMessage = 
    CreateInternalServerResponse(
        "Call to  Api failed. Response received: " 
        + (jsonResp["message"]));
```

But I'm not sure how I can add a cookie.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I dont have HttpResponseMessage, Even if I use Response.Headers , it doesnt have addcookie.  Other problem is CookieHeaderValue accepts Dictionary.

Comment: Can you share little bit more context? this is code is part of the an API Controller? If I understand it correctly you want to add some cookies to the response returned from your API, is that right? Can your share the code which returns a response without cookie?

Comment: Yes. I've added IActionResult for without cookie response. But I dont know how to proceed for cookies case. I've edited the original post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191376/using-cookies-in-asp-net-core-2-1

Comment: https://asp.mvc-tutorial.com/httpcontext/cookies/

Comment: Thanks Chetan, stackoverflow response helped too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below codes:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    //...

    var responseMessage = CreateInternalServerResponse("Call to  Api failed. Response received: " + (jsonResp["message"]));
    
    Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "cookieToken", new CookieOptions()
    {
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(4),
        Path = "/",
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = true,
    });

    return responseMessage;
}
```